# jira query to compare list fields

Tags: jira

I'm trying to write a query that will return all issues where the set of fixed version(s) is not the same as the set of affected version(s).

The naive solution of `affectedVersion = fixVersion` fails with:

```
The value 'fixVersion' does not exist for the field 'affectedVersion'.
```

Trying to use 'is' fails as well.

How can I do this? I'm willing to install any extra plugins if required, but I'm hoping there's just syntax that I dont know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely not possible with Jira out of the box. See the documentation on ["Advanced Searching"](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching) where it says "Be aware that it is not possible to compare two fields."

When I had this problem I didn't find any plugins that can do this, but maybe someone else knows one.

Answer (score 1):

Looked for a solution for this as well and came up with this filter creation.

I'm comparing the planned to the fixed (you can obviously do the same for affected instead).

Limitation is that you need to *maintain* the query for each release you are *fixing to*:

```
("Planned for Version" in ("2.3.0") AND fixVersion not in ("2.3.0")) OR 
("Planned for Version" in ("2.4.0") AND fixVersion not in ("2.4.0"))
```